# sqlite-fts3: custom tokenizer?

Tags: html, sqlite, tokenize, full-text-search

Does anyone here have experience with writing custom FTS3 (the full-text-search extension) tokenizers? I'm looking for a tokenizer that will ignore HTML tags.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I have no direct experience, but by doing a web search with "sqlite3 registerTokenizer" I found two tokenizers that can be used as a basis: [a snowball tokenizer](https://bitbucket.org/sevkin/snowball_fts3/src/15723faa51c8/snowball_fts3.c) and [a MeCab tokenizer](http://reddog.s35.xrea.com/wiki/SQLite%20Full%20Text%20Search%20with%20MeCab.html).